# React-Native: How to make Talkback recognize Touchable components as interactive?

Tags: android, react-native, accessibility

I'm trying to make my React Native app accessible.

In native, when I have a Button, TalkBack says my content description, then the component type and then a hint like:

> Double tap to activate.

How can I make Talkback read my React-Native button and place a hint like that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed page on react-native docs about [Accessibility](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibility.html).

Comment: My code is like this:

    `<TouchableNativeFeedback
      onPress={this.props.onPressInbox}
      accessibilityLabel={this.props.label}
      accessibilityTraits={['button']}
      accessibilityComponentType="button">
      {...children}
    </TouchableNativeFeedback>`

But Talkback only reads: "My label, Button."

It should read:
"My label, Button. Double tap to activate."

Comment: have you tried adding 'Double tab to activate' to accessibility Traits? `<TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={this.props.onPressInbox} accessibilityLabel={this.props.label} accessibilityTraits={['button Double tab to activate']} accessibilityComponentType="button"> {...children} </TouchableNativeFeedback>`

Answer (score 0):

```
  <TouchableOpacity
    accessible={true}
    accessibilityRole={"button"}
    accessibilityLabel={"sent an e-mail"}
  >
```

You could use `accessible={true}` to make it as a group. So the a11y frame would indicate this touchableOpacity.

Also providing role as "button", to make sure the talkback would say "double tap to activate".

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `<TouchableOpacity>` or `<Pressable>` element, you'll need to add `accessibilityRole="button"` for TalkBack to recognize it as a button, typically with a "tap to activate" announcement after any text on the element. If you're using it as a button, this is best practice.

If this fails for some reason, you can set the TalkBack announcement via the `accessibilityLabel` property, and indicate within that that the element's clickable. Note that this will replace any text the button has in the TalkBack announcement, so you'd want your full text within that property, e.g.

```
accessibilityLabel="Send an email, tap to activate"
```

These properties will generally behave the same on iOS, though iOS will automatically group elements within a `<TouchableOpacity>` or `<Pressable>`.

Documentation on `accessibilityRole` and other accessibility properties can be found [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/accessibility#accessibilityrole).